# Create Custom List Permission

Tags: permissions, 2013

There is a list. It has an admin group and member group.

1. I want admin group has full control
2. Member group can add new item but only see his/her items.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 2013 but I'm sure it's similar to 2010.

Go to your list settings. Click "Advanced Settings", under "Item-Level Permissions" you can change the settings for "Read Access" and "Create and Edit access" to only allow users to read, create, and edit their own items.

You can then go back to list settings, and under "Permissions Management" click "Permissions for this list" and you can break permissions inheritance and grant full control to the group of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question answered here : [Item-level permission problems](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61620/item-level-permission-problems)

What you need is modify to the standard view to show items that are only visible to the creator as outlined in the link.

For admins, you can create a page and insert the list webpart with standard view and it should solve your purpose altogether. Give unique permissions on this page to the admin group only.